# Finding length of shared sequence in R

Tags: r

I have a question. I have a table consisting out of two rows

```
00012121000012100110021212012121
11220212121221121212121212200000
    -             -       -
```

The line below the two lines with numbers is just for illustration. I would like to start to compare the two rows at the - in the middle and then find the position of the two incompatible stops 2/0 (left) and 0/2 right. It could also be the other way around (that 2/0 is on the right and 0/2 on the left). I do know the position to start from in the middle from another source. Is there an easy way to do find 2/0 or 0/2 to the left and the 0/2 2/0 (depending on what is on the left) on the right? and tell the position/

Answer (score 1):

It is not the most efficient way of doing it but you can use simple index comparison, e.g.:

```
s <- c("00012121000012100110021212012121",
       "11220212121221121212121212200000",
       "    -             -       -     ")
l <- strsplit(s, "")
l[1:2] <- lapply(l[1:2], as.numeric)

d <- l[[1]]-l[[2]]
#  [1] -1 -1 -2 -1  2 -1  1 -1 ...

## stop rule left: 2/0 => 2
stopsleft <- which(d == 2)
# [1]  5 29 31

## stop rule right: 0/2 => -2
stopsright <- which(d == -2)
# [1]  3 10 12 16 20 27

middlepos <- 19

stopleft <- tail(stopsleft[stopsleft < middlepos], 1)
# [1] 5

stopright <- head(stopsright[stopsright > middlepos], 1)
# [1] 20

target <- grep("-", l[[3]])
# [1]  5 19 27
```

Please note, that my right stop position differs from yours. I don't know why you choose position 27 instead of 20.

Comment: oh you are right with the stop position. Does it in this code matter which pattern (0/2) or (2/0) is on the right ot on the left?

Comment: You have to adjust the `which(d == 2)`/`which(d == -2)` accordingly. Or use `which(abs(d) == 2)` if the order never matters.

Comment: could you potentiallyupdate that in the answer I dont really see where it comes into it. Also the strsplit step in the beginning can be removed if the data is already in a matrix cant it?

Comment: you apprear to use a list?...in a matrix (if the data were in a matrix) would you justsubtract the value in row 1 from the value in row2?

Comment: the problem is that it does not completely not matter if the diff is -2 to d the left it has to be +2 to the right and the other way around

Comment: @user3419669: You can substract the values of row1 from row2 in your matrix. - I gave you a start and solved the main problem. I think it should be easy for you to remove the `strsplit` step, use a `matrix` instead of a `list` and handle the different stop rules for `d` with an `if`/`else` statement. I am not going to implement that for you.